# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory, while the file does exist and it's in the same folder

Tags: python, filenotfounderror

I'm coding something and I need to open a .txt file on the code. I have both the code and the text file in the same folder, yet I still get this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dis_rules.txt'. The code I wrote was directly taken from a different thread on this page, and obviouly the file name written in the code is identical. [Here's the folder with both files on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLFgf.png).

Here's the code I've used too:

```
fp = open(r"dis_rules.txt", 'r')
print(fp.read())
```

What could be wrong on this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the [current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-the-current-directory-and-files-directory) at the time of read?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72440639/attempting-to-read-file-in-same-directory-as-python-file-but-getting-filenotfoun/72440741#72440741

Comment: The current directory is indeed a different one to the folder, thank you for pointing it out. But how do I fix that?

Comment: you have to search for the answer yourself on google depending how you are running python (like a certain bar in your IDE or cd in the cmd, etc), please read the [before you ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make sure you do your own research before asking.

Comment: I have done my research before asking but since I'm new to Python and programming overall I might not know where to look. If I had found the answer when I did my research I wouldn't have asked here. I'm still trying though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comments you guys posted I got to solve the issue. As you all said, the problem was that the current directory of the file was different to the folder's directory. To solve this, I had to use the os.chdir() method to change the currently directory to the folder's directory, this way:

```
import os

path = "C:\\Users\\utente\\Desktop\\_rules2"
os.chdir(path)
```

After that I just added the code I posted on the question and it worked just fine.
Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I'm relatively new to python, and i've never seen this method of opening a text file... Try like this:

```
with open('dis_rules.txt','r') as f:
    print(f.readlines())
```

Also, not sure you need to use an r-string...
Tell me if that helps!

Comment: Problem is not that, most likely its because of conflicting path and working directory.

Comment: Yep, I tried that out and it didn't work, the problem lies elsewhere I guess. Thank you for trying to help though!

Comment: Oh ok, sorry... Weird.. Try creating a new file/ renaming it otherwise ...